# Javascript method execution and triggering event

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, jquery-events, eventtrigger

I am having trouble to clear a concept; say I have the following code snippet:

```
$('a.classA').on('click', function(){
  // something do here
});

$('a.classB').on('click', function(){
  // something do here
  $('a.classA').trigger('click');
  // rest of the code
});
```

We know Javascript executes sequentially. So when the method corresponds to the `click` event of `a.classB` is executing, then the programmatic triggering of the `click` event of `a.classA` will pause the current method execution and when the `click` event of `a.classA` would finish then it will execute the rest of the code? Or the method will be executed in different thread or something; although threading is not available in Javascript.

Comment: There must be a [better way of testing this](http://jsfiddle.net/MyzzK/)?

Comment: Just like trying something in IE and believing it's like in the specification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggering a "click" is a synchronous operation, so it's effectively like making a function call. You can use a timeout with a zero-millisecond delay if you'd like the operation to take place after the current event loop completes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` to make *asyncronous* trigger:

```
$('a.classB').on('click', function(){
  // something do here
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('a.classA').trigger('click');
  },1);
  // rest of the code       
});
```